# Spring Boot + Spring Integration Java DSL + AOP : Fails to proxy the Gateway interface

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, aop, spring-aop, gateway

Hi I have a spring boot application, which starts a spring integration flow, through a gateway interface, using Java DSL. Everything works fine on its own. I added AOP to capture exceptions, with `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)`

At this stage, it gives the error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'jobInitiator': Post-processing of
>   FactoryBean's singleton object failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not
>   generate CGLIB subclass of class [class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy54]:
>   Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a
>   non-visible class; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class class
>   com.sun.proxy.$Proxy54

When I remove the `proxyTargetClass = true`, it works but the advices are not triggered.

Any help? Is there a way to start the spring integration flow without a gateway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no class associated with the gateway `Proxy` so you can't advise it.

> Is there a way to start the spring integration flow without a gateway?

Instead of using the gateway, declare a bean of type `MessagingTemplate` and use `template.sendAndReceive(someMessage)` or `template.convertSendAndReceive(somePojo)` instead. See [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#channel-template).

(The gateway uses a `MessagingTemplate` internally; the gateway unwraps a `MessagingException` and throws the cause, the template does not).

It also does not support an error channel.

To get closer to the gateway functionality, you can subclass `MessagingGatewaySupport` and invoke its `sendAndReceive()` method(s).

Comment: Good Stuff! Thanks Gary.